# "Compare with yesterday and last week" checkbox disappeared in New Relic

Tags: heroku, newrelic

I've got a New Relic application set up and I'm used to check the "Compare with yesterday and last week" button in APM in order to analyse long term trends in the metrics.

Today this checkbox has disappeared. Is it related to my price plan or somehting to do with data retention? I am using New Relic as a Heroku addon and I did not receive any message mentioning this restriction so I am not sure if this is a bug or the end of a trial period that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're on the "Overview" tab, the time picker is set to "Ending now" and you're viewing the Transaction Time Chart (as opposed to the Transaction Histogram or Transaction Percentile view).

See [this thread](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/cant-compare-with-yesterday/35866) on the New Relic Technical Community for a similar reported issue.